# How can I include the CSS or JS files from a ZIP folder in my HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I have a zipped folder of all the CSS and JS files for my desktop Electron application. I am trying to refer a CSS file from this zip using the below syntax which isn't working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="../css/resources.zip/assets/styles/style.min.css">
```

Is this even possible or am I making some syntax errors?

Comment: Why not unzip first? A `.zip` file is not a regular directory, even though Windows (and maybe some other operating systems) might make it look like it.

Comment: I am zipping it just to reduce the application size. Seems like minification of scripts and styles is the only possible way for that.

Comment: strange this question was downvoted...i found this question useful despite zip not be the standard practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible without extensions. A zipped folder is rather a file than a directory, a folder with items not accessible by normal means.

Comment: I think I'll just have to keep it unzipped then

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a package like [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip).

You could open the zip using this and get the files you want and just add the file content to your page using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Its not the best method but it is possible.

Like @domdom said you could just unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your css into the html file

```
<style>
  h1 {
    color:black;
  }


</style>
```

Unfortunately, this can crowd up your html file, but it gets the job done. [Minifying](https://cssminifier.com/) can help with the crowd problem.